# How to make a file publicly viewable inside a bucket using TypeScript in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I would like to know how to change this Javascript code into TypeScript:

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
var myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

var file = myBucket.file('my-file');

file.makePublic(function(err, apiResponse) {});
```

I have been trying to change it like this:

```
import * as storage from '@google-cloud/storage';
const myBucket = storage.Bucket('my-bucket');

const file = myBucket.file('my-file');

file.makePublic(function(err, apiResponse) {});
```

However, Visual Studio Code is underlying this line (in bold):

const myBucket = **storage.Bucket('my-bucket')**;

If I place my mouse over that underlined line, I get the following message:

> [ts] Value of type 'typeof Bucket' is not callable. Did you mean to
>   include 'new'? class Storage.Bucket

So, I suppose that I have to instantiate the class using the keyword new, but the line still remains underlined by Visual Studio Code (in bold):

const myBucket = **new storage.Bucket('my-bucket');**

This time the error message changes:

> [ts] Expected 2 arguments, but got 1. constructor
>   Storage.Bucket(storage: storage.Storage, name: string): storage.Bucket

According to the error, I need to use two arguments.  One storage type and one string type.  I already have the second one (string type).  I am not sure how to create the storage one.

How can you create the first argument (storage type)?

If we see the Javascript example, it only asks for the second argument(string type). The Javascript code, somehow infers or has a default value for the storage type.  Is it possible to do the same in the TypeScript version of the same code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storage` is a function here:

```
import * as storage from '@google-cloud/storage'
const myBucket = storage().bucket('my-bucket')
```

You may need to pass parameters to `storage()` to get it to behave the way you want.  See the [API doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage).

You could also get a storage bucket instance via the Firebase Admin SDK if you're using Firebase and want to access your project default storage:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
const myBucket = admin.storage().bucket()
```

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for your help.  I started using the Firebase Admin SDK. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get public url from google cloud storage

clear instruction in github => just convert import to typescript import

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/blob/master/3-binary-data/lib/images.js

```
import * as Storage from '@google-cloud/storage'
import * as config from '../config';

const CLOUD_BUCKET = config.get('CLOUD_BUCKET');

const storage = Storage({
  projectId: config.get('GCLOUD_PROJECT')
});
const bucket = storage.bucket(CLOUD_BUCKET);
function getPublicUrl (filename) {
  return `https://storage.googleapis.com/${CLOUD_BUCKET}/${filename}`;
}

file.makePublic().then(() => {
  req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);
  next();
});
```

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage